# What is this tree with corky wings on the branches

Tags: identification, trees

This tree is located in an urban park in USDA zone 3a with winter temperatures to -40 deg Celsius. It has a trunk about six inches in diameter and is about thirty feet tall. In the winter I mistakenly identified it as Quercus macrocarpa or the Bur oak due to the prominent corky wings on the branches.

Now that the tree has leafed out it looks more like a beech tree with serrations on the leaves.  What species is this tree?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic elm leaf; tree shape is not very American elm. So ,rock elm ,ulmus thomasii, Twigs have corky wings like a winged elm ( winged elm grow further south ). However , there are some introduced  elm species like English elm that are similar but they do not have specific climate ranges ( in the US).

Comment: Yes, it's a rock elm and evidently at the northern limit of it's range.  More resistant to Dutch Elm disease and not quite as rare as one might think http://treescanadensis.ca/ulmus-thomasii-rock-elm/

Answer (score 1):

When I saw the leaves I thought Elm, so this led me to Ulmus alata, but in the specified location it is way out of normal range. Is there by any chance any sign of leaf miner which might tend to confirm elm of a sort? The specimen sort of has the beginnings of an elm vase shape, and U. alata is a slow grower, perhaps producing the compact shape seen here.